# How can I fix this ParseException error with NOT IN clause subquery?

Tags: database, hive, beeline

I am running this query through beeline

```
select * from sales.inventory

where customer not in
(select id
from sales.local);
```

This query gives me the next error:

Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 4:1 cannot recognize input near '(' 'select' 'id' in expression specification

Could anyone help me? Thanks!!

Comment: What Hive version are you running?

Comment: solved thanks, it was the space between lines